# Сделать ограничение

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения, kotlin

У меня есть поле, в которое я ввожу имя пользователя, а проверка на валидацию следующая:

```
private fun isNameValid() : String {
    val name = nameEditText.text
    if (!name.isNameValid()) {
        nameEditText.setError(AppResources.getString(R.string.error))
        nameEditText.requestFocus()
        return ""
    } else {
        nameEditText.setValid()
        return name
    }
}
```

В моём if'e есть метод extesion который реализован следующим образом:

```
fun String.isNameValid(): Boolean = !this.isBlank() && this.length > 1 && matches("""\p{L}+""".toRegex())
```

Мне сюда нужно добавить regex выражение таким образом, чтобы я мог добавлять в моё поле сколько хочу слов, а не одно как сейчас.

Как его правильно будет вставить в  мой метод?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, суть вопроса то?

Comment: [Регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) , [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) на что бы я посоветовал обратить внимание.

Comment: @rjhdby запихнуть \p{L} - ограничение в мой метод, ведь это есть ограничение, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: В Kotlin можно `Regex("""\p{L}+""").matchEntire(name)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew получается эту строку могу запихнуть в свой if? что будет означать что пользователь не сможет ввести большими буквами так?

Comment: Нет, почему же, `\p{L}` находит  как строчные, так и заглавные буквы.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew тогда в чем получается ограничение? просто прочитал в офф документации Any letter except an uppercase letter (subtraction). И так понимаю в котлине этой строки будет достаточно? не нужно дополнительно дописывать pattern/matcher?

Comment: Вы в вопросе не упоминаете ни строчные, ни заглавные буквы. Какие тут требования, условия к вводимому тексту?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew на самом деле хотелось бы разобраться как работают регулярные выражения в данном примере, а именно понять это всё таки ограничени p{L} и как его лучше использовать в данном методе. + к примеру если нужно применить для двух строк то как корректно  складывать их.

Comment: Что вам вообще нужно? Для валидации необходимы определенные требования. Какие они? Обновите вопрос. Я почти уверен, что решение укладывается в одну строку кода, но что надо - неяно. Добавьте примеры.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew обновил вопрос)

Comment: Удалите `this.length > 1`, хотя это и неважно, а вот к условию у меня снова вопрос: "добавлять в моё поле сколько хочу слов" - а как разделены слова? С помощью пробела? Тогда нужно использовать `matches("""\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*""".toRegex()`

Comment: this.length>1 это для количества символом в слове, ну как вы заметили это не важно. Да слова разделены между собой пробелом и пользователь может ввести одно слово, а может ввести 25 слов, ну то есть никак не ограничивать пользователя по кол-ву слов.

Comment: @Inkognito: Так вы решили проблему? Я заново перечитал вопрос и не нашел требований к регулярке. "Хочу №  слов" - это неясно для компьютера. Если вы хотите ограничить ввод до букв и пробелов, может, проще просто использовать `matches("""[\p{L}\s]+""".toRegex())`?

Comment: Не забывайте добавлять в комментарий `@`+username для оповещения пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Если между словами могут быть только одинарные пробелы, то задачу можно решить так:

```
fun String.isNameValid() = matches(Regex("\\w+( \\w+)*"))
```

Если же нужно учесть, что между словами может находиться любое количество пробельных символов, а также если допустимы пробельные символы в начале и в конце строки, то можно сделать так:

```
fun String.isNameValid() = matches(Regex("\\s*\\w[\\w\\s]*"))
```

Изучение регулярных выражений можете начать, например, со статьи [на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).